# Discretise data into groups

Tags: python, data-analysis, binning

I have a .csv file containing various data (exported from imagej) such as 'Area' for a range of samples (nearly 250). These samples relate to physical experiments where they can be split into two groups 'with' or 'without'.

I want to try bin my samples into these two groups.
I have tried using pandas.cut but haven't had any success as the binning options (as far as i know) are to use the values to bin, where i want to bin by index. I want to bin by a list of index e.g. [0:9,18:27] = with and [9:18,27:36] = without

here is some sample code:

```py
import pandas as pd

experimental_data = pd.read_csv(r'./experimental_data.csv')

ID = [0,9,18,27,36] #0:9 and 18:27 = with, 9:18 and 27:36 = without
Samples_sorted_by_ID = pd.cut(experimental_data.Area,bins=ID, ordered = True)
```

sample data:

[sample data snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fuq4P.png)
if anyone can offer any help that would be really helpful!
Cheers,
Pat

Comment: try `pandas`, probably that is what you are looking for. Also give us a snippet of code with the data and the expected output. At the moment it is not clear what you want and what does not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.